# how to fix "Invalid operands to binary expression "class" to "class"" error (repl.it)

Tags: c++

I'm currently coding a simple 2 player chess game. The current point that I'm at is finding what object (of a class) the user is trying to move based on the member variables of the class. I created a function to return the instance of the class based on the variables, but when I try to compare (==) the returned value to an object of the class, I get the "invalid operands to binary expression" error.

```
// this is the important class

class King{

private:

const char m_color;
int m_x;
int m_y;

public:

void setStartBlack(){
    m_color = 'B';
    m_x = 4;
    m_y = 0;
    board[m_y][m_x] = 'K';
}
void setStartWhite(){
    m_color = 'W';
    m_x = 4;
    m_y = 7;
    board[m_y][m_x] = 'K';
}

int getMX(){
    return m_x;
}
int getMY(){
    return m_y;
}
};

// this is the function I made to return the class instance

King checkPieceK(int x, int y){ // x and y is the column and row

if (blackKing.getMX() == x && blackKing.getMY() == y){
    return blackKing; // I should note here that blackKing is an 
// object of the king class and so is whiteKing
}
else if (whiteKing.getMX() == x && whiteKing.getMY() == y){
    return whiteKing;
}
else{
    return failureCondK; // this is what should be returned if the 
// piece doesn't exist at the location checked
}
}

// and here's what's happening at main()

while (GAMEOVER == false){

std::cout << " enter the row, column and type of the piece you 
want to move(e.g. \"G1P\" means \"G1,\" Pawn): ";
row = getchar();
col = getchar();
typ = getchar();
getchar(); // catches newline (\n or \0) char
row = toupper(row);
int newRow = detYval(row);
typ = toupper(typ);
if (typ == 'K'){
    if (checkPieceK(col - 1, newRow) == failureCondK){ // this is 
// the statement is where the error occurs

    }
}

GAMEOVER = true;
}
```

Comment: You seem to have all the pieces to create a [mcve]. Please create one and post it. It's difficult, if not impossible, to suggest anything useful without one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The compiler doesn't know what to do when you use the `==` operator on two `King` objects. You have to define the operation. This involves writing a function with a special name (`operator==`) that compares `King` objects.

```
class King {
public:
  bool operator==(const King &rhs) const {
    return m_color == rhs.m_color && m_x == rhs.m_x && m_y == rhs.m_y;
  }
  // whenever you define operator==, you should also define operator!=
  bool operator!=(const King &rhs) const {
    return !(*this == rhs);
  }

  // ...
};
```

If you want to compare kings, you can do `king.operator==(otherKing)` or `king == otherKing`. If you prefer, you can also define `operator==` as a non-member function (outside of the class).

```
class King {
  // ...
};

bool operator==(const King &lhs, const King &rhs) {
  return lhs.m_color == rhs.m_color && lhs.m_x == rhs.m_x && lhs.m_y == rhs.m_y;
}
bool operator!=(const King &lhs, const King &rhs) {
  return !(lhs == rhs);
}
```

Now you can compare kings with either `operator==(king, otherKing)` or `king == otherKing`.

You might need to put some thought into the definition of `operator==`. Do we really need to compare color, x and y? In this situation, you might get away with just comparing color (because there's a white king, a black king and an invalid king) or just comparing position (because you can't have kings occupying the same tile).

What I have just demonstrated is called [operator overloading](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operators) and it can be used for most operators in the language.

Answer (score 1):

You need to overload the == operator for the class.

```
class King{

private:
  bool operator==(const King& k) const
  {
    return m_x == k.m_x && m_y == k.m_y;
  }

  /* snip */
};
```